# Project Pages of Drupal

Tags: nodes

I have seen project pages in drupal under http://drupal.org/project/xyz. I don't know how that works really.

Is this a specific 'Content Type' it is, but each node (aka project) has extremely consistent layout where as the whole thing look more like an basic article or a book page. Also, the elements within also has sections and further content; so it doesn't look like a pure single node. Or is this a different entity using a module like [Project](http://drupal.org/project/project)? But it is not available for D7.

Specifically, I want something exactly like this, but i don't quite know how to make specialized and consistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal.org is using the Project module.

What you see as project page is a normal node to which the Project module adds extra fields. Keep in mind that the project page is also showing blocks shown just for those pages, and which are not part of the project page output.
The Project module automatically creates a path alias for every project node. That is the reason you see http://drupal.org/project/views, instead of http://drupal.org/node/38878; if you try the last link you will see you are accessing the Views project page.

[image: screenshot]

The fact the project page is just a content type is proved from the fact project is shown in http://drupal.org/node/add, which lists the possible content types for which a user can create a node.

[image: screenshot]

What you see in that page depends from the permissions you have on Drupal.org; as site maintainer, I see listed some content types a normal user doesn't see, such as the Story content type.

As alternatives to using the Project module there is the [Storm](http://drupal.org/project/storm) module, which is more complex, in some way, and lack integration with CVS, or Git repositories (as far as I can see).

> Storm is a structured system for project management, including:
>
> - Organizations, Teams, People,
> - Projects, Tasks, Tickets, Timetrackings,
> - Notes, Invoices, and Expenses.
>
> Each part provides permissions to control the sharing of data with other Drupal users, and based on assignment of projects/tasks/tickets to particular users or teams.

The difference is that the Project module has been thought to be used on Drupal.org, even if it can be used on other sites, and the main features are the ones required from Drupal.org.

The [Support Ticketing System](http://drupal.org/project/support) module implements a ticketing system, and a help desk.

> The support module provides a basic ticketing system and helpdesk that is native to Drupal, offering complete email integration.
>
> The Support module offers the following features:
>
> - Ticketing activity is illustrated with colorful charts (depends on the Chart API module).
>     -Tickets can be assigned to users (and users can view all tickets assigned to them).
> - Tickets support states (new, active, pending, closed, etc) and priorities (low, normal, high, critical, etc).
> - Configurable email notifications for new and updated tickets.
> - Email integration allows tickets to be created and updated via email, with support for attachments. New users can be automatically created. Ticket properties can be updated via email (using included support_mailcmd module).
> - Highly configurable client and user ticket overviews, highlighting tickets that haven't been updated for a long time.
> - Fully integrated with Drupal's search functionality, users can only search for tickets they have access to.
> - Supports an unlimited number of clients, each with their own configuration and access permissions.
> - Tickets are nodes, ticket updates are comments.

Comment: +1 thanks a lot. Support Tracking system is a bit different from my use. I am actually not using it for SW projects or customer co-ordination per say. Is storm ready for production env in D7? We dont have bandwidth for development or bug fixing really.

Comment: So far, there is just a development snapshot for the Storm module, which is used in 47 websites, out of the 846 sites using that module. (The data are referring to March 4, and are the last available from the project page.)